# Deploy OpenUI5 on phoenixframework

Tags: sapui5

I created my first openui5 hello world application on eclipse and want to deploy on my phoenix(elixir webserver) server.

Application structure:

[image]

And the app looks as follow:
[image]

My question is, how make the application ready to deploy?

Answer (score 2):

Its all static content. Copy all files and folders  inside Webcontent to your web server. You can put it to the web servers root,  but you don't have to. WEB-INF and META-INF are not needed.

Then copy the openui5 framework to the Webserver to a folder of your choice. You may have to change the bootstrap element to point to your sap-ui-core.js.

That's it. Optionally You can use the grunt-openui5 plugin to build a packaged preload file of your application.